# How to add a buttons to a MutableArray according to their tag number in objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

i have a view contains many sections(group of buttons) each section in the view contains unique id, i want to add buttons to an NSMutableArray according to their id,(i.e. when the user clicks a button i get the button id then add to the array all the buttons have that id) i wrote these code, but when i check the length of the array after adding i found it to be 0 !!
Hint: sec_0,sec_1,sec_2,sec_3,sec_4,sec_5,sec_6,sec_7,sec_8 is a predifined NSMUtable arrays.

```
-(NSMutableArray*)findButtonsSection:(UIButton *)buton{

NSLog(@"Inside findButtonsSection");
int tag_No=buton.tag;
for (UIButton* bton in self.view.subviews) {
    NSLog(@"Inside findButtonsSection2");
    switch (tag_No) {
        case 0:
                [sec_0 addObject:bton];
            NSLog(@"Number of buttons in array=%i",[sec_0 count]);

            break;
        case 1:
            NSLog(@"Button tag No=%i",buton.tag);

            [sec_1 addObject:bton];
            return sec_1;
            break;
        case 2:
            NSLog(@"Button tag No=%i",buton.tag);

            [sec_2 addObject:bton];
            return sec_2;
            break;
        case 3:
            NSLog(@"Button tag No=%i",buton.tag);

            [sec_3 addObject:bton];
            return sec_3;
            break;
        case 4:
            NSLog(@"Button tag No=%i",buton.tag);

            [sec_4 addObject:bton];
            return sec_4;
            break;
        case 5:
            NSLog(@"Button tag No=%i",buton.tag);

            [sec_5 addObject:bton];
            return sec_5;
            break;
        case 6:
            NSLog(@"Button tag No=%i",buton.tag);

            [sec_6 addObject:buton];
            return sec_6;
            break;
        case 7:
            NSLog(@"Button tag No=%i",buton.tag);

            [sec_7 addObject:bton];
            return sec_7;
            break;
        case 8:
            NSLog(@"Button tag No=%i",buton.tag);

            [sec_8 addObject:bton];
            return sec_8;
            break;
        default:
            NSLog(@"nnnnnnnnnn");            
    }

}

}
```

Comment: "when i check the length of the array after adding i found it to be 0" Which array did you check? Your code returns after it adds 1 item to any array that isnt sec_0.

Comment: it seems to be that, what can i do to add the all the buttons have the specified id instead of adding one item?

Comment: remove the `return sec_#` parts from the switch. Check my answer below with updated code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your arrays are all empty is because you return after you add any value to an array that isnt sec_0. You don't want those returns, as it will break out of your for loop. Try the code below:

You could also switch the array around to save you some lines of code and improve readibility.

```
-(NSMutableArray *)findButtonSelections:(UIButton *)button {
     NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sec_0, sec_1, sec_2, sec_3, sec_4, sec_5, sec_6, sec_7, sec_8, nil];

     int tag = button.tag;

     //BTW, this function will return all views, not just buttons
     for (UIButton* bton in self.view.subviews) {
         //So add this to make sure the view is a button
         if([bton isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {

              [[array objectAtIndex:tag] addObject:bton];
         }
     }

     return [array objectAtIndex:tag];
}
```

If you wanted to keep your switch code, try this below, but i don't recommend it.

```
-(NSMutableArray *)findButtonSelections:(UIButton *)button {

    NSLog(@"Inside findButtonsSection");

    int tag_No=buton.tag;
    for (UIButton* bton in self.view.subviews) {

        NSLog(@"Inside findButtonsSection2");
        switch (tag_No) {
            case 0:
                [sec_0 addObject:bton];
                NSLog(@"Number of buttons in array=%i",[sec_0 count]);

                break;
            case 1:
                NSLog(@"Button tag No=%i",buton.tag);

                [sec_1 addObject:bton];
                break;
            case 2:
                NSLog(@"Button tag No=%i",buton.tag);

                [sec_2 addObject:bton];
                break;
            case 3:
                NSLog(@"Button tag No=%i",buton.tag);

                [sec_3 addObject:bton];
                break;
            case 4:
                NSLog(@"Button tag No=%i",buton.tag);

                [sec_4 addObject:bton];
                break;
            case 5:
                NSLog(@"Button tag No=%i",buton.tag);

                [sec_5 addObject:bton];
                break;
            case 6:
                NSLog(@"Button tag No=%i",buton.tag);

                [sec_6 addObject:buton];
                break;
            case 7:
                NSLog(@"Button tag No=%i",buton.tag);

                [sec_7 addObject:bton];
                break;
            case 8:
                NSLog(@"Button tag No=%i",buton.tag);

                [sec_8 addObject:bton];
                break;
            default:
                NSLog(@"nnnnnnnnnn");            
        }

    }

    return [array objectAtIndex:tag];
}
```

Comment: "remove the button parameter", so how to determine the tag number of the button pressed!

Comment: i edited the question before you even commented to put it back in after i re-read your original question :P

Comment: But regardless, if you removed the button parameter, you could populate all the arrays with their buttons if you just switch based on the tag of each button, instead of just populating 1 array

Answer (score 2):

Form a C array out of those sec_x mutable arrays after they're constructed. Like this:

```
NSMutableArray *secs[] = {sec_0, sec_1....};
```

Then use indexing instead of switch:

```
[secs[tag_No] addObject:bton];
```

The square brackets in this case denote array element access, not an Objective C method call.

On a more general note, read up on plain old C. The Objective C/iOS tutorials often assume, without spelling it out, that you have some C background and start by explaining the Objective C object system rather than the C bits.

Comment: Don't you mean `NSMutableArray *`? `NSMutableArray` is an incomplete type.